# eonasdan datetimepicker not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using the eonasdan datetimepicker. This is the code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And its corresponding javascript code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           (function () {
                $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'LT'
                });
            });
        </script>
```

And these are the header files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="./angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

But I am always getting this error in my console

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
```

Comment: Your IIFE is missing parens `(function() { ... })();` at the end. Can you duplicate the error in plunkr or jsfiddle? It seems to work there with your scripts.